# not able to see Delete button when swpping UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am trying to delete `UITableViewCell` from `UITableView`.

Implemented `UITableViewDelegate`, `UITableViewDataSource` to my `UIViewController`.

Also implement all methods which need to define for above delegates these are like,

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Set UITableView to editing mode also,

```
  [tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
```

When i click on Delete button to set tableView in Editing mode, i can see '-'sign red button but when i clicked that button not able to see "Delete" button, also not able to see when swipe on cell.

I go through all posts from **stackoverflow**, but can't get solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing the **tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath** method. Try to add the code below to your implementation.

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

heres what i use to accomplish this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [myArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Comment: i already implemented above method... as given below
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) { 
    // Delete the row from the data source [self deleteRowsAtIndexPath:indexPath]; // Method used to delete row [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

Comment: but you never are actually removing the object from the array? at least thats what it seems like. the code i gave you works perfectly in an app im currently developing so try it the way i used it. maybe itll work for you too

Comment: thanks for ur reply, but for execute this function "Delete" button should appear. Once i click on that button this function gets called and deletion performed. But my problem is am not able to see "Delete" button.

Answer (score 0):

please remove

```
[tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
```

and just use this method

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return YES if you want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
```

and implement action on delete button
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:

```
(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 //add action on delete button
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method is used to display the delete button while swiping the selected TableViewCell.

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
       editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
}
```

This method will perform action on tapping the delete button while swiping the TableViewCell

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
        commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
        forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
}
```

This method will update the tableview after deleting the row form the table view

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
                   didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
}
```